Unity game throwing ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null, Parameter name:path
I am making a game in Unity using a TikTokLive Library by Frank v Hoof. I am currently working on saving gifters and amount of coins they gifted into a json file (which will be stored to a db when the game closes) but every time i recieve a gift and run the function, I get the error from the title. Been at it for the better part of 3 hours cant seem to figure out the issue...
Here is the initialization of the file path and start method:
 private string filePath;

 private void Start()
 {
     filePath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "/userGiftData.json");
     //filePath = "C:/Users/Kaki/Desktop/userGiftData.json";

     // Check if the file exists, if not, create it
     if (!File.Exists(filePath))
     {
         File.WriteAllText(filePath, "{}");
     }
 }

Here is the Init function which should call the function OnGiftUpdateValue on every gift:
 public void Init(TikTokGift gift)
 {
     if (gift == null || gift.Sender.UniqueId == null || gift.Gift.Name == null)
     {
         Debug.LogError("Gift or sender data is null!");
         return;
     }

     Gift = gift;
     Gift.OnAmountChanged += AmountChanged;
     Gift.OnStreakFinished += StreakFinished;
     txtUserName.text = $"{Gift.Sender.UniqueId} sent a {Gift.Gift.Name}!";
     txtAmount.text = $"{Gift.Amount}x";
     RequestImage(imgUserProfile, Gift.Sender.AvatarThumbnail);
     RequestImage(imgGiftIcon, Gift.Gift.Image);
     // Run Streak-End for non-streakable gifts
     if (gift.StreakFinished)
         StreakFinished(gift, gift.Amount);
     OnGiftUpdateValue(Gift.Sender.UniqueId, Gift.Gift.Name); //Line 93
 }

Here is the OnGiftUpdateValue function:
public void OnGiftUpdateValue(string userName, string giftName)
{
    // Read the existing JSON data from the file
Dictionary<string, int> userData = ReadUserDataFromJson();

    if (giftValues.ContainsKey(giftName))
    {
        int giftValue = giftValues[giftName];  // Retrieve the value of the gift

        // If the user exists in the data, update the total gift value, else create new
        if (userData.ContainsKey(userName))
        {
            userData[userName] += giftValue;
        }
        else
        {
            userData[userName] = giftValue;  // New user starts with the gift value
        }

        // Write the updated data back to the JSON file
        WriteUserDataToJson(userData); //Line 120
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError($"Gift '{giftName}' does not exist in the dictionary.");
    }
}

And in the end, ReadUserDataFromJson and WriteUserDataToJson functions:
 private Dictionary<string, int> ReadUserDataFromJson()
 {
     if (File.Exists(filePath))
     {
         string jsonData = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
         //return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, int>>(jsonData) ?? new Dictionary<string, int>();
         return JsonUtility.FromJson<Dictionary<string, int>>(jsonData);
     }
     return new Dictionary<string, int>();
 }

 private void WriteUserDataToJson(Dictionary<string, int> data)
 {
     string jsonData = JsonUtility.ToJson(data);
     //File.WriteAllText(filePath, jsonData);
     System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, jsonData); //Line 144
     Debug.Log("Data saved to: "+filePath);
 }

Also an image of the unity error i get on every gift (Btw once i remove the call function from Init, rest of the code works fine...):
Unity Error image
Thanks a lot for taking out the time of your day to read this! <3

Well sounds like filePath is not initialized the moment you try to use it ... Is something calling Init before your Start got the chance to run? In general you should move such initialization of own self contained class fields into Awake to at least reduce this type of race conditions .. but even further you could probably just use a property that initializes the field once

Sorry, English is not my first language so I dont really understand half of the terms you're using... Are You saying that if I move initialization of file path to Awake that might fix it? Also, Init function is called in different code that basically says 'On Gift call Init'

I would just try and use a directly initialized field private static readonly string filePath= Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "/userGiftData.json"); return _filePath; or in case Application.dataPath can't be used in that moment (don't know by memory right now) as fallback use  a lazy self initializing property: private static string _filePath; private static string filePath { get { _filePath ??= Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "/userGiftData.json"); return _filePath; } }

Oh actually you most probably will not be able to use that path in a built application ... you might rather want to use Application.persistentDataPath!

I see, ill give it a try, thanks a lot! :D
